# Limit results by removing duplicates, but keep the highest of the duplicates?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, duplicates

Not too sure how to explain it very well in the title.

To note: I'm using PHP and PDO for querying the sql database.

I have a table with a list of numbers that are not unique, and a 2nd column with a number that I only want the highest of - and only if the highest of them is above 50, example:

```
0 - 50
0 - 80
1 - 24
1 - 88
2 - 11
2 - 44
```

From the above, I would only want `0 - 80` and `1 - 88` returned, what is a good way of achieving this?

I can only think of an inefficient method which returns all rows and then compares one by one adding values to an array and replacing them if a higher one exists in a loop.

Comment: You want `group by` with `max()`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL query, MAX() + GROUP BY](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5657446/mysql-query-max-group-by)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check:

```
SELECT DISTINCT col1, MAX(col2) maximus
FROM my_table 
GROUP BY col1
HAVING maximus > 50
```