# GROUP BY changesChanges ORDER BY sorting

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-order-by

I have a web application written with PHP and MySQL.

The result of one SQL command (mentioned below) is something like this:

[image]

```
SELECT
   t.subject, c.parent_id, c.date_time 
FROM
   tbl_tickets_contents c
JOIN
   tbl_tickets t
ON
   t.id = c.parent_id
ORDER BY
   c.date_time DESC;
```

I want to remove duplicated items. So I changed the SQL script to this:

```
SELECT
   t.subject, c.parent_id, c.date_time 
FROM
   tbl_tickets_contents c
JOIN
   tbl_tickets t
ON
   t.id = c.parent_id
GROUP BY
   c.parent_id
ORDER BY
   c.date_time DESC;
```

I assumed this change will give me this result:

[image]

But the output was:

[image]

It seems **GROUP BY** changes **ORDER BY** sorting order. I wanted to have the records with newer `date_time`, but after this change I have records with older `date_time`!

How can I solve this problem? What is my mistake?

Comment: Try look this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5657446/mysql-query-max-group-by

Comment: @EllaSvetlaya, it did not give me what I needed. Result changed after applying `MAX()`, but only `date_time` for each result changed. Whereas I must see result in this order: `parent_id 2, parent_id 3, parent_id 1` regarding to stored `date_time` values.

Comment: Bro you didn't give the table structure.So it will better to give answer.

Comment: I think you need group by subject, because what if table have more tests in one parent?

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code and its working for me.

I change `c.date_time` to `MAX(c.date_time) as date_time` so you get latest date time.

And change order by `c.date_time` to `date_time`

```
SELECT
   t.subject, 
   c.parent_id, 
   MAX(c.date_time) as date_time 
FROM
   tbl_tickets_contents c
JOIN
   tbl_tickets t
ON
   t.id = c.parent_id
GROUP BY
   c.parent_id
ORDER BY
   date_time DESC;
```

**[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7d0c5/10)**

Comment: Did you pay attention to my comment in EllaSvetlaya's answer?

Comment: Sorry Bro. I try to make a better solution. please give me some time

Comment: did you check my SQL Fiddle Strawbery.

Comment: You need to change ORDER BY to: `ORDER BY date_time_max DESC;`

Comment: @ Mohammad Saberi see my latest Fiddle.I think you will get your expected result.