# Retrieving 1 pivot row per relation based on pivot values in Laravel belongsToMany relation

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

**Background** - I'm creating a system where administrators can create arbitrary fields, which are then combined into a form. Users then complete this form, and the values input against each field are stored in a table. However, rather than overwrite the previous value, I plan on keeping each past value as individual rows in the table. I then want to be able to display the contents submitted in each form, but only the most recently submitted value.

**Problem**

I have a model, `Service`, that features a belongsToMany relationship with another model, `Field`. This relationship is defined as:

```
public function fields()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Field')->withPivot('id', 'value', 'date')->withTimestamps();
}
```

The intermediary table has 3 values I wish to retrieve, `id`, `value` and `date`.

A `Service` may have 1 or more `Field`s, and for each field it may also have more than 1 pivot row. That is, a single `Service`/`Field` pairing may have multiple entries in the pivot table with different pivot values. For example:

*Table field_service*

```
id      | service_id | field_id | value   | created_at
------------------------------------------------------
1       | 1          | 1        | lorem   | 2018-02-01
2       | 1          | 1        | ipsum   | 2018-01-01
3       | 1          | 1        | dolor   | 2017-12-01
4       | 1          | 2        | est     | 2018-03-10
5       | 1          | 2        | sicum   | 2018-03-09
6       | 1          | 2        | hoci    | 2018-03-08
```

What I want is to get either:

- A specific row from the pivot table for each `Field` associated with the `Service`, or
- A specific `value` from the pivot table for each `Field` associated with the `Service`.

For example - in the table above, I would like the `Service` with ID 1 to have 2 `Field`s in the relationship, with each `Field` containing an attribute for the corresponding pivot value. The `Fields` attached would be specified by the corresponding pivot table entry having the most recent date. Something akin to:

```
$service->fields()[0]->value = "lorem"
$service->fields()[1]->value = "est"
```

I feel there's an obvious, 'Laravel'ly solution out there, but it eludes me...

**Update**

Somewhat unbelievably this is another case of me not understanding windowing functions. I asked a [question 7 years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5657446/mysql-query-max-group-by) that is basically this exactly problem, but with raw MySQL. The following raw MySQL basically gives me what I want, I just don't know how to Laravelise it:

```
SELECT services.name, fields.name, field_service.value, field_service.created_at, field_service.field_id
FROM field_service
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT field_id, max(created_at) as ts
    FROM field_service
    WHERE service_id = X
    GROUP BY field_id) maxt
ON (field_service.field_id = maxt.field_id and field_service.created_at = maxt.ts)
JOIN fields ON fields.id = field_service.field_id
JOIN services ON services.id = field_service.service_id
```

Comment: Do you mean "2 Fields" instead of "3 Fields"?

Comment: See what you mean - that was just an example - there's an arbitrary number of 'Fields'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public function fields()
{
    $join = DB::table('field_service')
        ->select('field_id')->selectRaw('max(`created_at`) as `ts`')
        ->where('service_id', DB::raw($this->id))->groupBy('field_id');
    $sql = '(' . $join->toSql() . ') `maxt`';
    return $this->belongsToMany(Field::class)->withPivot('id', 'value', 'created_at')
        ->join(DB::raw($sql), function($join) {
            $join->on('field_service.field_id', '=', 'maxt.field_id')
                ->on('field_service.created_at', '=', 'maxt.ts');
        });
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
$service->fields[0]->pivot->value // "lorem"
$service->fields[1]->pivot->value // "est"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Jonas. This is almost there - however the inner table isn't filtering by service_id, so it returns the latest field value entered for any service (as opposed to the specific service called. I need to add a 'where' clause into the field_service inner table  query, but I'm getting a question mark parameter at the end of the query when I add a where to the $join query

Comment: Adding: `$join->where('field_service.service_id', '=', DB::raw($this->id))` and `$join->where('field_service.status', '=', DB::raw("'published'"))` did the trick - just had to find the DB::raw method!